# Difference between bandmodel and bondmodel in semiconductor?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, binding-energy

I have confusion in the two models of semiconductor and it is as follows:

$1$- according to the bond model it says that the electrons which is bounded Silicon atoms,when we apply electric field this electrons will move opposite to the field and the empty state (hole) will move with the field. this according to bond model

but it's not the case in the band model, electrons in the top of valence band have negative effective mass and obviously negative charge so then it moves with the same direction as the applied electric field.

which is the right one every model say an opposite thing to the other ??

Comment: No, empty states (holes) in the top of the valence band have negative effective mass. Either way, the "bond model" is a casual analogy, band structure based on Bloch states in a crystal is a real theory with provable results.

Comment: @JonCuster, electrons in the top of valence band has negative effectivemass and negative charge so it's acceleration with the electric field